# Which registry tool do you use for your PC?

Tags: windows-registry

Hi everyone,

I just want to ask which registry cleaner you are using, because right now I have registry mechanic, but its not working for me. PC performance is also getting worse.

Thanks :)

Comment: You may want to try superuser.com for this kind of question.

Comment: Covers the same ground as [Windows registry and system cleaner applications ?](http://superuser.com/questions/6668/windows-registry-and-system-cleaner-applications)

Answer (score 3):

I never, ever use a registry cleaner.

They all stand a very good chance of making a right mess of your machine, and have a very slim chance of giving any real benefit.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off uninstalling all the crap-ware you probably have (including registry cleaners). If you have any anti-virus software installed, that's probably slowing you down more than anything (unless your drive is full and fragged). Follow best practices/common sense when browsing the web, use web-based email and you'll not have to worry about viruses. Uninstall everything your not using and run msconfig and experiment by unchecking everything in the startup tab. After that, if something you really need doesn't work, find it in the startup list and recheck it.

Comment: This is EXTREMELY bad AND STUPID advice. While emails are a major attack vector for malware, so are malicious ads which you can easily capture (for example if you do not have an ablocker installed). - Even Google and Yahoo have served malicious ads inadvertedly in the past. "Good behaviour" is still the best protection, but not sufficient. 
And lastly, any kind of portable media - say a flash drive from a colleague could contain malware (autoplay disabled?) - as could a sincerely shared file.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand not wanting to use a registry cleaner, many feel the same about defraggers. I follow the arguments on both sides and would say that you have to decide for yourself, and results may vary.  All I know is from personal experience, I use both regularly and always have the fastest, cleanest running computer in the office and among family and friends, so no science, just opinion (though it could just be that I am really careful about researching what I install and run in the first place).  To answer this question specifically I like to use both
RegSeeker http://www.hoverdesk.net/freeware.htm
and
CCleaner http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

With either I suggest taking it easy, looking at exactly what it wants to do, and making sure you agree, at least until you are comfortable with them.

As an aside, I also like MyDefrag http://www.mydefrag.com/

Comment: I think most recommend Not using one because most users will cause more damage than good using a reg cleaner, as with anything in life you have to know what you are doing, most do not. Its a general rule not a definite one.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Eusing Free Registry Cleaner](http://www.eusing.com/free_registry_cleaner/registry_cleaner.htm), afterward using [Eusing Free Registry Defrag](http://www.eusing.com/free_registry_defrag/registry_defrag.htm) to compact the registry.

However, I wouldn't bet that the registry is the cause of the slow-down.